# Downloading / Exporting fails in chrome for records exceeding 2.5K

Tags: php, google-chrome, opencart, export-to-csv

***In OpenCart framework***

1. After clicking Export button, all the customer selected product list catalogues will be exported containing all the data.
2. Here the Options to Download button appears
3. Once after clicking download, for the records say about < 2.5K it'll  download in CSV format successfully in chrome as well as firefox browser.
4. For records more than 2.5K,

   - Especially with FireFox Browser it takes too much time for about 5K records it takes 15 mins to execute and downloads successfully.
   - But in case of Chrome it fails with Download Failed - Network error

***From my controller file:***

```
function download(){
        $export_type = $this->request->post['export_type'];
        if($export_type=='p'){
           $customer_id = $this->customer->getId(); 
           $this->load->model('account/wishlist'); 
           $this->load->model('catalog/product'); 
           $noofproducts = $this->model_account_wishlist->getTotalWishlist(); 
           $data = array(); 
           ob_start();
           $product_ids = $this->model_account_wishlist->getProductIdFromWishList();
           $products = $this->model_account_wishlist->getProduct($product_ids); 
           $filename = "data_export_" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv";   
            header('Content-type: application/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            header("Expires: 0");

            $result = $this->ExportCSVFile($products) ;
            $xlsData = ob_get_contents();
            $length = ob_get_length();
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

            $response =  array(
                        'op' => 'ok',
                        'file' => "data:text/csv;base64,".base64_encode($xlsData),
                        'filename' => $filename
            );
            ob_get_clean();
            ob_end_flush(); 
            die(json_encode($response));

        }



    }


    function ExportCSVFile($records) {
        // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
        $fh = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
        $heading = false;
        if(!empty($records))
          foreach($records as $row) {
        if(!$heading) {
          // output the column headings
          fputcsv($fh, array_keys($row));
          $heading = true;
        }
        // loop over the rows, outputting them
        fputcsv($fh, array_values($row));

          }

          fclose($fh);
       }
```

***Here is my View file (tpl) in Ajax Script:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getNotifications() {
    $('#export_import_notification').html('<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button> <div id="export_import_loading"><img src="view/image/export-import/loading.gif" /><?php echo $text_loading_notifications; ?></div>');
    setTimeout(
        function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'index.php?route=account/wishlist/getNotifications&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json) {
                    if (json['error']) {
                        $('#export_import_notification').html('<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button> '+json['error']+' <span style="cursor:pointer;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;float:right;" onclick="getNotifications();"><?php echo $text_retry; ?></span>');
                    } else if (json['message']) {
                        $('#export_import_notification').html('<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button> '+json['message']);
                    } else {
                        $('#export_import_notification').html('<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button> '+'<?php echo $error_no_news; ?>');
                    }
                },
                failure: function(){
                    $('#export_import_notification').html('<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button> '+'<?php echo $error_notifications; ?> <span style="cursor:pointer;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;float:right;" onclick="getNotifications();"><?php echo $text_retry; ?></span>');
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#export_import_notification').html('<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button> '+'<?php echo $error_notifications; ?> <span style="cursor:pointer;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;float:right;" onclick="getNotifications();"><?php echo $text_retry; ?></span>');
                }
            });
        },
        500
    );
}
```

Do we need to import certificates from the chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solved it's Due to the Proxy Settings of Domain Name Server on the Server
 Side.***

Try these following Steps given below:

- Remove / Disable any DNS Services from the IPv4/v6 Settings
- Don't use any Proxy Servers(HTTP, SOCKS v4/v5)
- Disable DNS pre-fetching
- Flush out your browser cache (temporary internet files)